# How to retrieve first page visit location value from Query Sheet Formula against a corresponding row

Tags: sql, google-sheets-formula

I have this data in Google Sheets.

[image: Raw Data]

I am using this query in Google Sheets to group the data

`=query(gadata,"select A,B,C,SUM(D) group by A,B,C,1")`

This is the result:

[image]

How can I get the first-page location under the C column against the corresponding Client ID? Page Location will change each time the user visits the page but I am interested in the first page i.e. **Page A against each Client ID**

How can we achieve that?